# Draggable many elements with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I need to be able to drag all the `.note`s on the page, but when i use `draggable()` from the jQuery UI, it only works for the first `.note`. I have jQuery UI downloaded and is working.  When I click the page it makes a new `.note` so I think that this is a cloning problem.  Here is the code

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="wrp">
         <h1>Click to make a new note!!!</h1>

        <hr>
        <div class="note">
            <p class="remove"><b>X</b>

            </p>
            <div class="time"></div>
            <hr>
            <textarea class="item"></textarea>
            <div class="saved"><span class="msg"></span>

            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$(".note").closest('.note').draggable();
```

(I will not include all my JS)

Fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/cjhind/zfxj3cps/46/

Any advise?

Comment: `$(".note").closest('.note').draggable();` ??? Provide minimalistic sample in question itself. `When I click the page it makes a new .note` So initilaize draggable on it, once added

Comment: Why u use closest method? just use `$(".note").draggable()`

Comment: I added `closest()` to try to fix it, but then forgot to take it off

Comment: @A. Wolff, that was my question, how do I do that?

Comment: @ClayH add `$(note2).draggable();` as soon as u add `note2` object into dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this extra line in your onclick function because jquery cannot recognise new items. It is like it has already did target the items with .note and you need to retarget them. Take care because this will load again the script and it will act twice. so as many items you insert you can see by firebug that it is calling script more times. If you need more info let me know.

```js
$('#wrp, #wrapper').click(function showNote() {
    $('.note').fadeIn();
    $(".note").closest('.note').draggable(); // ADD THIS TO GIVE YOUR NOTE THE ABILTY TO BE DRAGABLE
});
```

Did this help?

Comment: THANKS!!!  This worked once i took out the `.closest()`.  For some reason it didn't work with that in it.

Comment: If you need any info let me know. :)